# TabLayoutPanel and gwt-slider-bar

Tags: gwt, gwt-tablayoutpanel

I tried adding a sliderbar using http://code.google.com/p/gwt-slider-bar/  code to  a TabLayoutPanel but the sliderbar is not displayed even if it works well on a DeckPanel.

Have anyone succed to do the same thing with this code or using another alternative?

Comment: Can you display other widgets in the TabLayoutPanel? Is it just the slider bar that won't appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better way to make a sliderbar in a TabLayoutPannel using the class http://code.google.com/p/listwidget/source/browse/trunk/web/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/gen2/#gen2%2Fclient with the CSS and gifs available in the same directory.

I hope this will be helpful